# I comment out code in my iPad app, but it still gets executed...how is this possible?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

I have a calendar program that I am trying to convert to iPad (using XCode4, no storyboards, but running on the Simulator).

It currently is not behaving correctly when I move to a previous month (I get a blank screen before the view is re-drawn).  So I commented out the code that does the actual creating and drawing of the screen, and the screen is still re-drawn!  I comment out other code, and the same thing happens... it's as if it is ignoring the commented statements!

I am dumbfounded as to why this is happening... I have done multiple cleans, straight builds then run... same thing happens.

Any ideas?

Comment: probably we need to see at least the commented code.

Comment: An unmatched brace, parenthesis or other syntax erro can cause both the problems you describe.

Comment: Please post the code segment that is problematic.

Comment: starbolin:  is there an easy way to check for matching parenthesis, or some free program that will do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried clearing the cache of the simulator?

From the simulator menu:

`IOS Simulator > Reset contents & settings`

Comment: that did it... at first I just closed the simulator, then decided to do the reset... and that found an error that I wasn't aware of.  Thank you so much... too bad I spent about 4 hours on this! :D

Answer (score 1):

Try cutting out the code from Xcode. If it still runs then something is seriously wrong. Also try duplicating the project folder in finder and run the new project, it has solved some weird xCode behavior for me.

Answer (score 0):

An unmatched brace, parenthesis or other syntax error can cause both the problems you describe.

Comment: upvotes are nice. Downvotes are good too, as it gives the answerer the chance to improve his answer. By not leaving a comment, this chance is effectively taken away. But I think it's a good answer: +1